# Pausing a javascript database query until setTimeout has finished

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a problem. I am querying a database and going through each result from the DB. The DB has 2 columns Name and Time. Now what i want the javascript to do is display that Name for the amount of time that is held in the database. I've tried to do this using setTimeout().

after SELECTing from DB:

```
function (transaction, result) {
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = result.rows.item(i);
    $('div.box').html(row.name);
    var countdown;
    var countdown_number;
    countdown_init();

    function countdown_init() {
        countdown_number = 11;
        countdown_trigger();
    }

    function countdown_trigger() {
        if (countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown_number--;
            document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
            if (countdown_number > 0) {
                countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', row.time);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Now, my problem here is, i believe, to do with threading in javascript (but i may be wrong). When the countdown starts, it does not pause the execution of the loop, but rather starts the countdown on a new thread and carries on in the loop bringing up the next DB entry and crashing out with all kinds of errors.

So how do i get around this? I have thought about adding flags.. but i'm not sure how this could work.  I have a feeling (i hope) there is a straightforward answer to this but not sure what it is.

Comment: First out, you have unmatched parenthesises, and on the third line, you need square brackets, like `result.rows.item[i];`. Now, where do you want to put your text? Can you provide some HTML markup and also describe what you want to do? Also, do you have a framework like jQuery at hand?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function (transaction, result) {
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = result.rows.item(i);
    $('div.box').html(row.name);
    var countdown;
    var countdown_number;
    countdown_init();

    function countdown_init() {
        countdown_number = 11;
        countdown_trigger();
    }

    function countdown_trigger() {
        if (countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown_number--;
            document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
            if (countdown_number > 0) {
                countdown = setTimeout(function(){countdown_trigger();}, row.time);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Many thanks and yes, sorry my code example was very sloppy as you and the other commenter have pointed out and yes this does fix it, but the underlying problem of not being able to pause the DB loop while the setTimeout runs remains